# RSS Feed Custom Title?

Tags: hooks, rss

For some reason my RSS feed is repeating the site title twice without a space, obviously quite annoying.

BlognameBlogname for example.

Is there any hook i can use to have a custom title for the RSS Feed?

So i could have a title 'This is My RSS Feed for Blogname' or anything i wanted?

Is this possible or am i stuck with the double name.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**: Bad answer removed.

Here is the working code:

```
function custom_blogname_rss($val, $show) {
    if( 'name' == $show )
        $out = 'Custom Blog Name';
    else
        $out = $val;

    return $out;
}
add_filter('bloginfo_rss','custom_blogname_rss', 10, 2);
```

Don't forget to change *Custom Blog Name* to something useful.

Put that code into a plugin.

Comment: Do you know how to alter the feed title for just one category? I currently get "Company >> Workers' Compensation" from my feed, but when displaying in a feed reader I need it to say "Company >> WorkCompEdge Blog".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `add_filter('wp_title_rss', 'custom_feed_title', 10, 2);` to change the feed channel title

```
function custom_feed_title($title) {
    return "THIS IS MY NEW FEED TITLE";
}

add_filter('wp_title_rss','custom_feed_title', 10, 2);
```

Comment: It works, but the callback's argument (and it's only 1, not "10, 2") is not the title. It has been the title separator but is unused as of 4.4.0, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title_rss/ Thank you anyway.