# RSS Feed Custom Title? (code placing)

Tags: rss, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [RSS Feed Custom Title?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51005/rss-feed-custom-title)

For some reason the RSS feed of my wordpress blog is repeating the site title twice without a space.

"BlognameBlogname" for example.

I want to change it to "Blogname"

I found this answer but it doesn't say where to put the code - [RSS Feed Custom Title?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51005/rss-feed-custom-title)

can anyone help me with that bit??

Thank you!

Comment: Where have you tried the code from the linked answer?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that it needs to be added in the functions.php file in your theme