# Change rss title of individual feeds?

Tags: categories, rss, feed

I want to set a custom title to indiviual rss feeds. Right now my post feed runs under a page called podcasts and the title of my rss feed then becomes `<blog name> » podcasts` because it is the feed of the podcasts page.

However I would like to replace the slug `» podcasts` with the subtitle of my blog.

How can I replace the title of the feed under posts or category?

I have seen the answer [RSS Feed Custom Title?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51005/rss-feed-custom-title) here but this does not remove the slug for me ... but appends it!

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy Fix ... since I use feedburner I can use their "burn feed title" service, which does exactly what I want!